# ubuntu 16.04 : Android Emulator shows balck screen

Tags: android, linux, android-studio, android-emulator

I am using ubuntu os, I have installed android studio in it.
I had downloaded two emulator images 22API (Abi- 86_64)  and 19 API (Abi- arm-7A).
When I start the emulator then it shows the black screen.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 16.04 in newly launched so it has take time to some bug fixes.

so plz use  **genymotion**  to run your app.

Comment: I cant used genymotion. Is their any other solution to resolved this.